# How to add spacing between the words in a <p> tag and align them with text boxes in the next div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following is the code for the form which I wrote:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="unlabelled">
            <p class="bg-primary">Items<span>Quantity</span><span>In Kit</span></p>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unlabelled-items" placeholder="Enter code or description">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="in-kit">
                    <button class="btn-primary" id="add-btn">Add</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
```

I am using bootstrap here. And I have the top paragraph heading with a class="bg-primary" which gives a nice background for the heading. I have two text input fields, a checkbox and a button. I want to align the text in the above paragraph with these fields.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pETm.jpg

I want the Items text to be aligned in center with the first text field, Quantity with the second text field and the In kit with the check box.

As you can see in my code, I added span tags around the text. I experimented with it by adding margin properties to these span tags, but it didn't work properly. I tried a bunch of   it works okay but I atleast need 15 to 20 of them which even didn't solve my problem.

Is there any alternative for this? I could even try other alternatives for the p tag too.

Thank you.

Comment: This isn't really clear as to what you want to accomplish. You talking about "Items text", but I'm not really sure what this is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can at least get you started, it's just `rows` and `columns` and some minor CSS. The problem you'll have is on a mobile device, if you want this to remain completely horizontal it'll start to break down.

```css
.well-md.well-head {
  background: #3973a6;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.checkbox {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="row well well-md well-head">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <p>Items</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p>Quantity</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p>In Kit</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unlabelled-items" name="unlabelled-items" placeholder="Enter code or description">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" id="in-kit" name="in-kit">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add-btn">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your text descriptors into columns that match with the columns for you inputs. Like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="unlabelled">
<p class="bg-primary">
            <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group col-md-5"> Items</div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">Quantity</div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">In Kit</div>
</div>
</p>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unlabelled-items" placeholder="Enter code or description">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <input type="checkbox"  id="in-kit">
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <button class="btn-primary" id="add-btn">Add</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```